# dot net Core 3.1 API HttpRequest returns usually bad request without even sending the request

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, httprequest, httpresponse, bad-request

I have a strange issue with my HttpRequest, i have 2 application one is clientside and the other one is RESTAPI, the issue is i am trying to update my entity by sending a request which the content is Json

```
 public async Task<bool> Update(string url, T obj, string id)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url+id);
        if (obj == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return false;

        }
       
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        var client = _client.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", GetBearerToken());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

And here is my clientapp controller below;

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> EditUser([FromForm] UserDTO userDTO ,string id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage", "Error");
        }
        userDTO.Id = id;
        await _userRepository.Update(EndPoints.UserEndPoint,userDTO,id);
        return RedirectToAction("GetUsers");
    }
```

and i dont know if it is necessary because it doesnt hit even the breakpoint but i am also showing my RESTAPI code below;

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Update user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="userDTO"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>   
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]

    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(string id, [FromBody] UserDTO userDTO)
    {
        var location = GetControllerActionNames();

        try
        {
            _logger.LogInfo($"{location}: Requested an Update for id: {id} ");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || userDTO == null || id != userDTO.Id)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{location}: Request for Id: {id} is not sucessful");
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _logger.LogWarn($"{location}: Data was incomplete!");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var isExist = await _userRepo.IsExist(id);
            if (!isExist)
            {
                _logger.LogWarn($"{location}: with Id: {id} is not exisist");
                return NotFound();
            }

            



            var usermap = _mapper.Map<CompanyUser>(userDTO);



            if (usermap == null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarn($"{location}:  Data is empty");
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var response = await _userRepo.Update(usermap);

            if (!response)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{location}: Update is failed ");
                return NotFound();
            }
            _logger.LogInfo($"User is Updated");
            return NoContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return InternalError($"{location} - {e.Message} - {e.InnerException}");
        }
    }
```

RESTAPI code is working when i try with PostMan.
But from the client side where i send the request it sometimes works but usually gives bad request as response instanly i mean not even go to my RESTAPI. Can you help to resolve this strange problem.

Comment: `it doesnt hit even the breakpoint but i am also showing my RESTAPI code below` Do you mean that it does not hit `UpdateUser` method while you make a PUT request from client side? Please make sure you make request to correct endpoint by checking the specified url. And if possible, please share the actual/testing posted data you used that cause bad request error.

Comment: @FeiHan yes sir it doesn't hit the breakpoint on my `UpdateUser` method. I checked my endpoint and it is okay the strange thing is system sometimes works without any issue but often from my client side the `Update` method it doesn't send any request and instantly gives bad request response. Sir, I can share the data from my swagger documentation if it is okay for you? Because i am using `Microsoft identity user model` and my additional entity fields which can updateable.

Comment: `system sometimes works without any issue but often from my client side the 'Update' method it doesn't send any request and instantly gives bad request response` If you installed such fiddler etc tool, you can try to capture request sent from your client app, then check the actual request with data and compare the failed request with the working one that you sent from postman, which might help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will do as you said and i will comeback with results.

Comment: Hello sir, i think i find the problem but i still don't know how to handle it. i used fiddler as you requested and it helped me ,so what i observed when something is wrong(receiving an error) on `RESTAPI` side strangely my session  disappears but i am creating session on client side okay i am using `Microsoft identity user on API` side and i am generating `jwt` on API side but i really don't understand  how to manage this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, on my API Login
Because i was using `Microsoft Identity` and when i use `await PasswordEmailSignInAsync(userName, password, false, false);` it automatically genereates application cookie on my API side and i used fiddler to capture requests and i saw there when i get an error or on my API side when the thread exits the application cookie also expires after that when i made a new request from my Client to My API it was giving the bad request on my client side instantly.

So i changed my signin method to `var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userDTO.Email); var result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user,  userDTO.Password);`

in order to avoid from the application cookie creation. I had already `JWT` token structure in my application but was useless because default `authorized` attribute was not using `bearer schema` and i modified my `startup.cs` a little help from [**Authorize Attribute not working with JWT Access Token in ASP.Net Core**[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475858/authorize-attribute-not-working-with-jwt-access-token-in-asp-net-core)

and now everything works without any problem!.

```
[Route("login")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginDTO userDTO)
    {

        var location = GetControllerActionNames();
        try
        {
            var userName = userDTO.Email;
            var password = userDTO.Password;
         
            _logger.LogInfo($"{location}: User:{userName} - Attempted to Login");
            //var result = await PasswordEmailSignInAsync(userName, password, false, false);
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userDTO.Email);
            var result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, userDTO.Password);

           
            if (result)
            {
              
                _logger.LogInfo($"{location}: User:{userName} Logged in Succesfully");
                var tokenstring = await GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
                return Ok(new { token = tokenstring });
            }
            _logger.LogWarn($"{location}: User:{userName} couldnt logged in ");
            return Unauthorized(userDTO);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return InternalError($"{location} - {e.Message} - {e.InnerException}");
        }
    }
```